# Editing two scheduled tasks with powershell in one script

Tags: powershell

I use this two commands in powershell to edit two scheduled tasks

```
schtasks.exe /tn Task1 /sd 2015-01-01  /ed 2015-02-02 /rp mypassword
schtasks.exe /tn Task2 /sd 2015-04-04  /ed 2015-05-05 /rp mypassword
```

I would like to know if i can use one line command to edit both tasks.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's harder to make this a one liner when multiple pieces of information need to be changed. Lets try to pass an array of hash tables to `Invoke-Expression`

```
@(  @{Name = "Task1";StartDate = "2015-01-01";EndDate = "2015-02-02"},
    @{Name = "Task2";StartDate = "2015-04-04";EndDate = "2015-05-05"}
) | ForEach-Object{
    Invoke-Expression ("schtasks.exe /tn {0} /sd {1}  /ed {2} /rp mypassword" -f $_.Name, $_.StartDate, $_.EndDate)
}
```

If you had a CSV file with the columns `Name`, `StartDate`, `EndDate` then you could pipe that right into the `ForEach` we have there. That was you don't need to declare the array statically in the code.

Most PowerShell code can be written in one line. Just depends how horrible you expect it to look for the next person.

Comment: Name and date also changes

Comment: @Redadublex yeah... that should have been obvious. It was late. I updated the code a little.

Comment: nice answer it's array or hash table ?

Comment: @SoheilHashemi its an array of hashtables :). It's set up that way so that we could use `Import-CSV` without changing the process code.

Answer (score 0):

Script-like approach:

```powershell
# Set password
$Password = 'Passw0rd'

# This is multidimensional array, i.e. an array that contains other arrays
# Each of those sub-arrays contains commandline parameters for schtasks.exe
$Commands = @(
    @('/tn', 'Task1', '/sd', '2015-01-01', '/ed', '2015-02-02', '/rp', $Password),
    @('/tn', 'Task2', '/sd', '2015-04-04', '/ed', '2015-05-05', '/rp', $Password)
)

# Iterate sub-arrays, and run schtasks.exe with commandline arguments from each
$Commands | ForEach-Object {& 'schtasks.exe' $_}
```

One-liner:

```powershell
@('/tn', 'Task1', '/sd', '2015-01-01', '/ed', '2015-02-02', '/rp'), @('/tn', 'Task2', '/sd', '2015-04-04', '/ed', '2015-05-05', '/rp') | ForEach-Object {& 'schtasks.exe' ($_ + 'Passw0rd')}
```